# What is meaning of the 2 and never param in comma-dangle?

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

What is the usage of this ?

```
"comma-dangle": [ 2, "never" ],
```

What is 2 and never here?

Answer (score 2):

The first item `2` is a generic setting for any ESLint rule. When [configuring rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#configuring-rules) you can set the severity level of the rule. You can use the numeric value or string value, both mean the same thing:

- `0` (`"off"`) to turn off the rule, so it does not trigger.
- `1` (`"warning"`) to produce a warning if the rule is breached.
- `2` (`"error"`) to produce an error if the rule is breached.

For ESLint itself there is no difference between warnings or errors. In both cases your code does not conform to a rule. However, some tools might differentiate. It is common for build tools to fail the build if errors are encountered but still produce a successful build if there were warnings.

It is usually a good idea to leave relatively minor things as warnings only and serious problems as errors. For example, stylistic rules like [spaces around `=`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops) might just produce a warning, while more serious issues like [unreachable code](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable) might instead be errors because it is a potential bug.

---

The `"never"` is a specific setting for [the comma-dangle rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle). Some rules are only a toggle on/off (with "on" being warning/error level) while others have extra settings. The comma-dangle rule can be configured for when and where dangling commas are allowed. The value `"never"` means that they should never appear. From the documentation:

> Examples of **incorrect** code for this rule with the default `"never"` option:
>
> ```js
> /*eslint comma-dangle: ["error", "never"]*/
>
> var foo = {
>     bar: "baz",
>     qux: "quux",
> };
>
> var arr = [1,2,];
>
> foo({
>   bar: "baz",
>   qux: "quux",
> });
> ```
>
> Examples of **correct** code for this rule with the default `"never"` option:
>
> ```js
> /*eslint comma-dangle: ["error", "never"]*/
>
> var foo = {
>     bar: "baz",
>     qux: "quux"
> };
>
> var arr = [1,2];
>
> foo({
>   bar: "baz",
>   qux: "quux"
> });
> ```